# How to add custom item in text selection menu without implementing an activity?

Tags: android, textview

I wanted to add a new item without imnplementing an activity as it wouldn't make sense for other apps to see that item. Is there a way to do this with a callback?

Answer (score 0):

Try to hide the field in the same activity and then whenever you want to make some working just make it visible or else access them without making visible like hidden data's in activities.